How to set up the first and second reviewer (tiered approval) on Github
Hi experts out there -
I'd like to set up the GitHub in that once A approves the pull request it goest to the B. so it's sort of tiered approval process. I have been searching for a while but can't seem to find the solution. Does anyone have experience like this?
Thanks,

I wonder if something like this GitHub Action would work:
name: Tiered Approval

on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  tiered-approval:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check for first reviewer approval
        if: github.event.review.state == 'approved' && github.event.review.user.login == 'reviewerA'
        run: |
          echo "First reviewer approved"
          gh pr edit ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} --add-assignee reviewerB

References:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-when-your-workflow-runs/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-when-a-pull-request-is-approved
https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_edit

Otherwise, there are some 3rd party tools looks like they have this feature:

https://4.pullapprove.com/docs/pullrequests/turns/
https://docs.mergify.com/workflow/request-reviews/#hierarchical-review-system

